# weights of layers in backpropagation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, backpropagation

I searched through the internet a lot but could not come to the conclusion why do we use weights in each layer of backpropagation algorithm. i know that the weights are multiplied to the output of previous layer to get the input of the next layer, but i do not understand why do we need these weights? Please help
Thanks Ark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the weights there could be no learning. Weigths are the values which are adjusted during the backpropagation learning process.  A neural network is nothing more than a function and the weights parametrize the behavior of this function.

To better understand first look at a single layer perceptron such as the ADALINE.